# Hi Im having trouble fitting the Table that is inside a JScrollPane in a Panel

Tags: java, swing

```
table1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));

JScrollPane pt = new JScrollPane();
pt.setViewportView(t);
pt.setSize(800, 500);

JPanel x = new JPanel();                 
x.add(pt);
x.setBackground(Color.decode("#323232"));

x.setSize(800, 500);

frame1[enter image description here][1].add(x);
frame1.setVisible(true);
```

[image]

I want to fit the table in the whole gray area. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
table1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
```

Don't hardcode a preferred size.

You can suggest a size by using:

```
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
```

Then the size of the scrollpane will be the preferred size of the table.

```
pt.setSize(800, 500);
...
x.setSize(800, 500);
```

Don't use setSize(). The layout manager will determine the size based on the rules of the layout manager.

If you want the table to grow/shrink as the size of the frame changes then 
your panel should use a `BorderLayout`. Then you just add the scrollpane to the panel and the scrollpane and table will expand/shrink to fill the available space.

Or just add the scrollpane directly to the frame. The content pane of the frame already uses a BorderLayout.

So the basic problem is how you nest panels on the frame.

Comment: @Tabz, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.